How to plug a different consensus algorithm in Hyperledger Besu
So here is what I want:- Suppose we have created a new consensus mechanism, so I want to see how fast or slow it is, while fulfilling it's basic tasks. What are the functions that I need to re-implement in my binary distribution, so that it could be run properly? (Or is it even possible)
What's my progress:- Properly running a network of 7 Besu instances, all mining transactions (ran through a js file calling) on all the different instances randomly
